# Azure function vs durable function for long running process in premium plan

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm planning to use Azure functions to process large files and it is a long running process( > 1 hour). The file processing is triggered by queue message. The function app will be running in premium plan. As the function timeout looks same for both regular Azure function and durable functions, do I get any advantage if I chose durable functions for this long running task ?. As I'm using storage queue, the failed processing will be taken care by default after visibility time of queue message.

Also the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) says , Premium plan execution is only guaranteed for 60 minutes, but technically unbounded. Does that mean any execution over 60 minutes is not guaranteed at all ?

Comment: *Does that mean any execution over 60 minutes is not guaranteed at all* Correct. If you need such a long runtime maybe an azure function is not the best fit for your scenario.

Comment: If you have any another solution for this use case, could you please suggest ? Almost every solution I see is dealing with Azure functions. I need the solution to scale based on queue messages.

Comment: Ok, can you tell us more, like *process large files*, what exactly does that mean? How is it done?

Comment: When large file is created in storage, a notification with file details is sent to storage queue. An application enqueues the message,  reads the lines from file in storage and then stores into DB. Very simple but long running task. When more messages are in the queue, the application should scale accordingly

Comment: May you can split the reading of the lines in batches and use the [fan-out pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc#fan-in-out) to get the job done.

Comment: I thought about that. But that might not fit the case always. Lines in a file might vary and no guarantee that splitting the read will finish within 60 minutes. Maybe I should look in the direction of something like AKS

Comment: Or Azure Data Factory...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs#azure-functions) Azure Functions aren't the best fit for long-running tasks:

> Azure Functions is not a recommended option for large, long-running
> tasks because they can cause unexpected timeout issues. However,
> depending on the hosting plan, they can be considered for
> schedule-driven triggers.

[Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc) are used for statefull processing, with features like fan out/fan in, chaining etc..
Not sure if you get any advantage for your usecase by using them.